# Получение элемента из массива по значению id

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив:

```
this.items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'test3'
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'test4'
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'test5'
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'test6'
}];
```

Как мне получить элемент c `id=6`?

Пробовал вот так: `this.items[6]`, но не получилось

Comment: `this.items[5]`

Comment: @VueBeginer изучите лучше основы языка, прежде чем браться за изучение фреймворков.

Comment: Неправильно сформулировал вопрос, меня интересует элемент с id 6

Comment: `this.items.find(i => i.id === 6)` , но я согласен с @Swartex - подучить js Вам стоит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), который возвращает первый элемент, удовлетворяющий заданному условию:

```js
this.items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test2'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'test3'
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'test4'
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'test5'
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'test6'
}];

var result = this.items.find(item => item.id === 6);

console.log(result);
```

---

Получить все элементы по заданному условию (например, если id не уникален), можно аналогично с помощью метода [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)